# Is there an API for setting user profile icon/tile pictures for Gnome 3?

Tags: gnome, gnome-3, gnome-shell

I am trying to programmatic-ally set the Gnome 3/GDM 3 user profile/tile/face picture for a user's account in Gnome3/GDM. This is my first attempt at a simple program for Linux and I'm unfamiliar with the APIs and my searching has yielded little useful information. It seems like one can write data to a .face file but this doesn't seem to take affect (or perhaps my file type/specs are wrong). I found from [this forum post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61637/where-is-the-users-profile-picture-stored-in-gnome-3) that the information is stored in a user-specific directory under /var/lib/AccountsService/users, however I want my program to run with regular user privileges and writing (directly) to this file would require elevated privileges (despite an unprivileged user being able to specify an image for their account via the Gnome settings GUI).

Ideally, I would like to do the same for KDE/KDM and Gnome 2 versions as well. Any information would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

OK, here's the part I *can* shed some light on:

On any Unix'y OS, you *can* always fall back on the GECOS field update function `putpwent`. Traditionally, the “Real Name” is the first part of the GECOS field in the user record, up to the first `,`.  Different systems store different extended information after the `,`, including things like department names, home and office phone numbers and the like.

In Gnome 2, “they” used to use ~/.face as your personal face icon. However, there are all kinds of situations in which one user can't look into another's home folder (including root: things like network filesystems, encrypted loopback homes, and more), so this was abandoned at some point (I believe 3.0) in favour of the /var/lib/AccountsService/icons/$YOURNAMEHERE location.

In the spirit of Gnome 3, the new system (the one you most likely want to use) is the Accounts Services DBus service. You can obtain a user object over DBus, and alter it. The interface is `org.freedesktop.Accounts` / `org.freedesktop.Accounts.User` and has methods like `SetRealName` and `SetIconFile`. There are also a “bunch” of other methods for things like location, language, eMail, …

**PS**: you can also use `libaccountsservice` to interact with it without calling the DBus yourself. EG: `void           act_user_set_real_name             (ActUser    *user,
                                                   const char *real_name)` and `void act_user_set_icon_file             (ActUser    *user,
                                                   const char *icon_file)` are exported from that library.

However, I *don't* know if K (or which version(s) of K) might be looking at this DBus service. So, if you really want to set up the K information, I'm afraid I don't know…

For what it's worth, you can also just let the user adjust it themself with

```
       gnome-control-center user-accounts
```